# JSON filter a JSON with wildcards and keynames

Tags: json, jq

How to parse a JSON to when a few values are string and other are list.

I have a list like this:

```
{
  "abc": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "def": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "ghi": [
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "name": "HELLO",
      "useless": "DO NOT WANT THIS"
    }
  ],
  "jkl": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "HI"
    }
  ],
  "mko": {
    "enabled": false,
    "something unwanted": 123
  },
  "pqr": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

Trying to filter only by the two key(`enabled` and `name like abc`):

```
{
  "abc": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "def": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "ghi": [
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "name": "HELLO"
    }
  ],
  "jkl": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "HI"
    }
  ],
  "mko": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "pqr": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

Tried several answers on SO, but nothing is giving the desired result. I am not a regular consumer of JSON so this question might sounds stupid.

```
jq -r '[*].enabled' file
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '*' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[*].enabled
jq: 1 compile error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `objects` and `arrays` to select the items to update with `|=`, then `with_entries` to access the `.key` which can be queried with `IN`:

```bash
< file jq '
  (.[] | objects, (arrays[] | objects))
    |= with_entries(select(.key | IN("enabled", "name")))
'
```

```json
{
  "abc": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "def": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "ghi": [
    {
      "enabled": false,
      "name": "HELLO"
    }
  ],
  "jkl": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "HI"
    }
  ],
  "mko": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "pqr": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/l1jywvb4Kzl)